# Unable to get React component props value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on Tic-Tac-Toe app and after each click on TD, I would like to insert and render my X or O component.. Everything is working just fine, except when I've tried to run checkWinner function. I have a problem with getting ID from component. This component is inside Matrix (2D array).
When I try to console log this array field, this is what I get

[image]

It's new to me, and I've never seen anything like this. My goal is to reach **id:"x"** prop.

So I've tried to do that like this :

```
//Horizontal check
for(let i=0;i<values.length;i++){
  let xCount=0;
  let oCount=0;

  for(let j=0;j<values[i].length;j++){
    if(values[i][j].props.id === 'x'){
      xCount++;
    }

    if(values[i][j].props.id === 'o'){
      oCount++;
    }
  }

  if(xCount === 3){
    console.log('X wins!');
  }

  if(oCount === 3){
    console.log('O wins!');
  }
}
```

But I get **TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined** . I really don't know why is this happening. That Id is important for me because as you can see depending on ID, count is rising. When your is 3 ,player will win.

This is how I'm inserting components on td click to matrix

```
if(values[row][column] === " "){
  if(sign === true){
    newValue[row][column] = <X id="x"/> 
  }else{
    newValue[row][column] = <O id="x"/>
  }
}else{
  return;
}
```

Comment: values[i][j].props .... you store props in your matrix array ?

Comment: yes,as you can see  I store whole <X  id="x"/> component in matrix

Comment: can you reproduce this on (https://codesandbox.io/) ??
i think that you aproche should work but better solution is to cep matrix array only with values and render this array. not to keep array of react objects.

Comment: yes sure.. Ill do that tomorrow. But If i do that by your way, i mean in matrix will be only strings. Is there any ways I can make condition or function which will go thru matrix and if there is value of X it will render my X component into td? thank

Comment: you can put in matrix what you like, 1Mb obeject for each cell as well. what you need. but wehen you store referencec to React components and if you don't doing it by useRef, then you can have problems with it. they can by not actual etc. I think thaty this aproche can by not stable. From the other hand you shuld separte you model from view implemataion. What if you want to store  data ? you will serialize and deserialize React component ?

Comment: What if you whant send data to server witch will made some manipluation and send it back ? What if you whant make multiplayer and you have to send game state to other user, you will send React components ? there is many aspects why you shuld make your model sepearted from view.

Comment: thank you for advices. Now, I have rebuild whole app ,so user can select how many rows and columns he wamt to have. But I have small problem with inserting into matrix.. can you please look at it what can possibly be the problem?

Comment: this line values[row][column] === " "... shows that in array can be string yeap ? but in this line values[i][j].props.id you are shure that you have react component right ? so if you have string and then you try get props of string you get undefined and you try get id of undefined.... "Cannot  get id of undefined" you can write values[i][j]?.props?.id then you don't get error but still probably it will not work.

Comment: do you please have discord on something like that where we can chat a little ?

Comment: [i turn on chat](https://codesandbox.io/live/2dbruoo)

Comment: Hey Robert, are you here? I've got one more question on you

Comment: yep still .... i fight with react native

Comment: and do you have one minute ?

Comment: yeah sure give me what you got

Comment: can we go please again in codesandbox?

Comment: can you create sandbox with your reproduction and paste link

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-albattani-lox1y?file=/src/Components/Icons/Replay.jsx

Comment: you have to turn on chat room

Comment: sorry.got it now

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/live/3bz1irz

Comment: Hey robert ,are you there ?